# How can I register on an image src changing using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

Is there something like

`$('img').onSrcChange(function(){alert("Changed");})` that will trigger when the `src` attribute on the image changes?

Comment: Hmm I dont really understand why you need that. How are you gonna change the src attr in the first place? I'm guessing, javascript. You can have a callback function as you change the src attr?

Comment: @peduarte - I'm changing the image myself with javascript, but it's part of a template that will be used several times during the page ... and I wanted to be notified whenever any image changes on the page (I have a grayed out "save" button that is only enabled once an image changes somewhere on the form). I can accomplish this in other ways, but still I think the question is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that works for images, hence:

```
 $('img').load(function(){alert("Changed");})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.load()` for this

```
$('#ImageId').load(function(){
  // src has changed
});
```

More informations about [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#fn)

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

no, I am guessing you are not the one changing the image source - maybe instead if you attach the image.onload event you'd know when a NEW one is loaded (and displayed).

Would that help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$('img').change( function() { ... } );` ; then if you see that this event is triggered for many reasons, simply save image path in a var and see if it changed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are second level events specified by W3C like DOMAttrModified event. Have a look here: [DOM-Level-2-Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)

Maybe this jQuery plugin will help you.
[Darcy Clarke's $.watch() plugin](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/)

This will work on any css attribute changed. With some modfications this will do the trick for src also.